# destructuring - error duplicate declaration 'hour'

Tags: javascript

I am using destructuring to create a start and end time:

```
  const {
                startYear: year,
                startMonth: month,
                startDay: day,
                startHour: hour,
                startMinute: minute
            } = event.start_date_details;
            const {
                endHour: hour,
                endMinute: minute
            } = event.end_date_details;
```

Any ideas?

Events json:

```
  "events": [
        {
            "id": 518,
            "global_id": "wordpress.rguc.co.uk?id=518",
            "global_id_lineage": [
                "wordpress.rguc.co.uk?id=518"
            ],
            "author": "1",
            "status": "publish",
            "date": "2017-12-14 12:11:42",
            "date_utc": "2017-12-14 12:11:42",
            "modified": "2018-01-11 10:04:49",
            "modified_utc": "2018-01-11 10:04:49",
            "url": "http://wordpress.rguc.co.uk/event/another-one/",
            "rest_url": "http://wordpress.rguc.co.uk/wp-json/tribe/events/v1/events/518",
            "title": "another one",
            "description": "",
            "excerpt": "",
            "image": false,
            "all_day": true,
            "start_date": "2018-01-31 00:00:00",
            "start_date_details": {
                "year": "2018",
                "month": "01",
                "day": "31",
                "hour": "00",
                "minutes": "00",
                "seconds": "00"
            },
            "end_date": "2018-01-31 23:59:59",
            "end_date_details": {
                "year": "2018",
                "month": "01",
                "day": "31",
                "hour": "23",
                "minutes": "59",
                "seconds": "59"
            },
            "utc_start_date": "2018-01-31 00:00:00",
            "utc_start_date_details": {
                "year": "2018",
                "month": "01",
                "day": "31",
                "hour": "00",
                "minutes": "00",
                "seconds": "00"
            },
            "utc_end_date": "2018-01-31 23:59:59",
            "utc_end_date_details": {
                "year": "2018",
                "month": "01",
                "day": "31",
                "hour": "23",
                "minutes": "59",
                "seconds": "59"
            },
```

Comment: take another name?

Comment: I guess you need to swap all the identifiers...

Comment: Can you show `event`?

Comment: you're destructuring both `event.start_date_details.startHour` and `event.end_date_details.endHour` to `const hour`

Comment: The correct English word for `destructing` is `destroying`. I guess you successfully managed to do so. Taking a little extra care when authoring question titles might be good advice.

Comment: I actually meant `destructuring`, typed it too quick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for destructuring (BTW destructing is the wrong term) is different. You need to specify keys you match before colon and variables you declare after colon.
Maybe you wanted:

```
 const {
    year: startYear,
    month: startMonth,
    day: startDay,
    hour: startHour,
    minutes: startMinute
} = event.start_date_details;
const {
    hour: endHour,
    minutes: endMinute
} = event.end_date_details;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're destructuring both `event.start_date_details.startHour` and `event.end_date_details.endHour` to `const hour`. Change it to

```
const {
  start_date_details: {
    year: startYear,
    month: startMonth,
    day: startDay,
    hour: startHour,
    minutes: startMinute
  },
  end_date_details: {
    hour: endHour,
    minutes: endMinute
  }
} = event;
```

so that you have the variable `startHour`, `startMinute`, `endHour`, and `endMinute` instead mapped from `event.(start/end)_date_details.(hour/minutes)`.

See [MDN's Destructuring Assignment - Assigning to new variable names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names).